# Keyboard shortcuts for dynamic menu items (Keynote)

Tags: keyboard, keynote

I often find myself creating Keynote presentations with lots of extra slides.  I then go through and skip a bunch for a particular class.

To make this slide choice easier, I added a keyboard shortcut for the "Skip Slide" and "Don't Skip Slide" menu commands.  Unfortunately, they don't work consistently.  In fact, it only seems that one at a time will work, which I think is a function of the fact that the menu item changes based on whether the selected slide is set to be skipped or not.

If a slide is selected that is hidden, the "Slide" menu will show "Don't Hide Slide."  If I look at the menu by clicking "Slide," then the "Don't Hide Slide" keyboard shortcut will work.  But, then if I select a slide is that is not hidden, the "Hide Slide" keyboard shortcut won't work.  I can get it to work by opening the "Slide" menu (where I can verify that it shows "Hide Slide" and my keyboard shortcut).  But, after that, the "Don't Hide Slide" keyboard shortcut stops working.

My question then: How do I get to use a keyboard shortcut for a menu item that is not in the menu at a particular time?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am looking at a similar issue of how to create a Keynote presentation that is a subset of a larger possible set of keynote presentation.

Comment: @JimMcKeeth, no solution yet.  Still bugs me every day.

Comment: Would a macro be an acceptable solution?

Comment: @TimothyMueller-Harder, Yes.  Anything that keeps me from "right-click Skip slide, Right-click Show slide" would be acceptable.

Comment: Do you happen to have Keyboard Maestro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't solve the general case problem of how to assign a keyboard shortcut for any dynamic menu item, but it ***does*** solve the specific problem of having a keyboard shortcut to hide or display slides in Keynote.

We can work around the shortcut problem because Keynote is AppleScriptable.

Create a new **service** in **Automator**.

The service takes **no input** in **Keynote.app**.

The service has a single action: **Do AppleScript**. The script (in all its one-line beauty) is:

```
tell application "Keynote" to tell current slide of the front slideshow to set skipped to not skipped
```

Save the service as "ToggleSkipped".

Use the **Keyboard Shortcuts** tab within the **Keyboard** pane of **System Preferences** to bind the service to an unused keystroke.